# Need help extracting data from a floppy disk formatted by an old drum machine

Tags: mount, filesystem, data-recovery, floppy

Alright, for context I make music using an old drum machine which uses 3.5" floppy disks (Emu SP-1200) and I am trying to take a look at what the OS binary and sound file formats are like.

But I'm unable to mount a floppy that was formatted by the machine, I guess it's because it uses a custom file system.
Is there any way to mount the floppy or dump the data from it?

This is the error I'm getting with nautilus, and udisks tells me the same thing (/dev/sdc: can't read superblock):

> Unable to access "Floppy Disk"
>
> Error mounting /dev/sdc at /media/louis/disk: Command-line `mount -t
>   "auto" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdc"
>   "/media/louis/disk"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount:
>   /dev/sdc: can't read superblock

I am using an old apple USB floppy drive.

Comment: "old apple"... that probably means it will have a specific filesystem. can you create a disk dump? Maybe it is easier to analyze it then.

Comment: My only suggestion is to try Ubuntu Studio, it contains a number of multimedia modifications.